# C++ inheritance not returning the correct values

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class base
{
public:
  int a;
  int b;
  void read();
  void display();
protected:
  int c;
};
void base :: read()
{
  cout<<"\nEnter values of a , b and c :";
  cin>>a>>b>>c;
}
void base :: display()
{    
  cout<<"\nValues of a,b and c :"<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c;
}
class derived : public base
{
  int x;
public:
  int y;
  void read();
  void display();
protected:
  int z;
};
void derived :: read()
{
  x=a;
  y=b;
  z=c;
}
void derived :: display()
{
  cout<<"\nValue of A :"<<a<<" "<<x;
  cout<<"\nValue of B :"<<b<<" "<<y;
  cout<<"\nValue of C :"<<c<<" "<<z;
}
void main()
{
  clrscr();
  base b; 

  cout<<"\nBase Class :";

  b.read();
  b.display();
  derived d;
  cout<<"\nDerived Class :";
  d.read();
  d.display();       

  getch();
}
```

Input  & Output: 
Base Class :
Enter Values of a , b and c: 1 2 3

values of a ,b and c : 1 2 3

Derived class:
Value of A : 1342 1342 
Value of B : -14 -14
Value of C : 11330 11330

I would like to use this code so that i could easily understand inheritance of the private , public and protected data ...

Please correct this code so that i could actually get to know about c++ inheritance 
or please do reply with the code that explain c++ inheritance ..

Comment: Please indent your code properly instead of giving each line its own random indentation.

Comment: You don't do any polymorphism in your code sample, so I fail to see why you'd expect inheritance to affect anything. Whatever resource you use to learn C++, it's time to find a better one.

Comment: You should state which values you expect to see.

Comment: No we must *not* remove our comments. Once you ask a question it is not just yours, it is out in the public. I am restoring the question as it was originally asked so that the comments and responses will continue to make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you instantiate `d`, you do not initialize the data members of the base class. Their value is undetermined (no initialization is performed on default initialized built-in types or PODs), and reading from them is actually undefined behaviour.

You must make sure that you initialize the base class data members before you read from them. There are many ways to do that, depending on your needs. At the very least, you could make sure they get zero-initialized by value initializing them in the constructor:

```
class base
{
 public:
  base() : a(), b(), c() {} // default constructor
  ...
```

This will result in your call to `d.read()` setting `d.x`, `d.y`, `d.z` to `0`, since all it does is assign from `a`, `b`, and `c` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

A method of a derived class does not automatically call the same method of the base class - it *replaces* the base implementation, it doesn't *add to* it. If you want to use the base class implementation too you have to do that yourself.

```
void derived :: read()
{
    base::read();
    x=a;
    y=b;
    z=c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create the instance of `Derived` it DOES NOT get the values of `a` `b` and `c` you assigned from console to the instance of `Base`: it's another, independend, object!

```
 void derived :: read() {
     x=a;
     y=b;
     z=c;
 }
```

This actually puts garbage inside `x` `y` and `z`.
You can call `base::read()` inside `derived::read()` to initialize `a` `b` and `c`

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you tried to do something like the following:

```
   #include<iostream.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    class base
    {
     public:
         int a;
         int b;
         virtual void read();
         virtual void display();
     protected:
         int c;
     };
    void base :: read()
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter values of a , b and c :";
        cin>>a>>b>>c;
    }
    void base :: display()
    {    
        cout<<"\nValues of a,b and c :"<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c;
    }

    class derived : public base
    {
         int x;
     public:
         int y;
         virtual void read();
         virtual void display();
     protected:
         int z;
     };

     void derived :: read()
     {
         base::read()
         x=a;
         y=b;
         z=c;
     }

     void derived :: display()
     {
         base::display()
         cout<<"\nValue of A :"<<a<<" "<<x;
         cout<<"\nValue of B :"<<b<<" "<<y;
         cout<<"\nValue of C :"<<c<<" "<<z;
     }

     void main()
     {
         clrscr();
         base b; 

         cout<<"\nBase Class :";

         b.read();
         b.display();
         derived d;
         cout<<"\nDerived Class :";
         d.read();
         d.display();       

         getch();
     }
```

Please note that to use polymorphism you should use the virtual keyword in order not to mask the function completly, however, that would be relevant in case of pointer and allocating to some base pointer an object of the derived type(s).

Also note that the way you implemented read will actually put garbage to xyz as abc are not read throug the read function of the base object, since no one ever calls it. So that is why you are getting random values there, instead of values entered in the console.

I suggest reading a bit about c++ polymorphism.
I find the resource below a good tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

I hope that this helps.